# SQLite android NDK

Tags: sqlite, android, android-ndk

I'm trying to use a custom function in sqlite3. 
I found no way in Java to do that so I moved on android-ndk, but now 
I'm having troubles integrating sqlite3 sources in my project. 
Compiler give me an error 'sqlite3_api' was note declared in this 
scope. 
In my source "sqlite3ext.h" is included (sqlite3 amalgamation is also included in project).

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems trying to get SQLite with SEE (SQLite Encryption Extensions) to compile and work. In the end I found http://code.google.com/p/sqlite3-android/ (the 2 downloads dated 17th February, the march downloads added some extra complications that didn't do what I wanted)

Once I had that working I included in the see.c with sqlite3.c and soon got it all working.